# I need to change the missing values of a matrix using loop for

Tags: r, statistics

I want to change the missing values in the columns of the matrix z, creating a matrix w, these new values must be the result of the maximum value of the column divided for the minimum value of the column where the missing value is:

```
set.seed(1206);

y <- x <- 12 + sqrt(06) * rnorm(5000);

y[sample(x = 5000, size = 200, replace = F)] <- NaN;

z <- data.frame(matrix(y, ncol = 20));
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `na.aggregate`

```
library(zoo)
z1 <-  na.aggregate(z, FUN = function(x) max(x, na.rm = TRUE)/
          min(x, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
z1 <- z %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace(.x, is.na(.x), 
      max(.x, na.rm = TRUE)/min(.x, na.rm = TRUE))))
```